# Static scope in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my app I'm showing a big table of data.
And as always I'm saving all the data i need to display in the `$scope` variable.

The problem is, with that much data in the DOM and also being watched by angulars digest loop the site lags a lot. Because I'm just showing static data, that can't be manipulated i would like to have a static scope that can not be manipulated on that very view and performs better.

So my question is, is there something like `$scopestatic`?

Comment: You want https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once

Comment: I agree that you need something line `angular-once` or `bind-once` libraries here, but first you need to be sure that this is exact the problem. The [batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) plugin for chrome can show you which watchers take most of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your performance problem most likely comes from too many data bindings. If it's only static data, you need to get rid of that.

I suggest you use a directive instead, creating DOM elements from your data. You only need to do it once and your website should perform much better without so many useless bindings.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need should be [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)

Another problem may be that showing a big table directly to user sounds like a bad idea. Human brain can not process too many datas. We can filter or paginate them for user instead.